# MAMP PRO and local DNS

Tags: dns, ping, synology, mamp

I have a local DNS on a Synology and a MAMPRO on a Mac. I develop locally on the Mac and I want now to give access to the website from local network (by VPN).
With a `nslookup`the DNS indicated the correct IP of the Mac. But when I ping the name I haven't any response.

Has someone any idea on the source of the problem ?

```
[ iMac ] nslookup test.local
Server:     192.168.0.35 <== DNS server / Synology
Address:    192.168.0.35#53

Name:   test.local
Address: 192.168.0.30

[ iMac ] ping test.local
ping: cannot resolve test.local: Unknown host
[ iMac ] ping 192.168.0.30
PING 192.168.0.30 (192.168.0.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.30: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
```